# Как сделать иконку андроид приложения в верхнем левом углу кликабельной?

Tags: activity, android, java

Всем добрый вечер!
Встал вопрос: возможно ли заменить иконку андроид приложения в верхнем левом углу на необходимую и сделать ее кликабельно?
Необходимо по ее нажатии вызывать другую активность. Смотрел варианты с меню, но большинство из них доступны с версии 4.0
Буду очень рад любой помощи в данном вопросе!

Comment: До 4-й версии нет возможности работать с ActionBar. Поэтому там нужно изощрятся и использовать отдельную библиотеку ActionBarSherlock

Comment: Во-первых, ActionBar появился не с 4.0, а с 11-й версии API, то есть с android 3.0. А во-вторых, помимо ActionBarSherlock, есть же support library, содержащая в себе реализацию ActionBar для 2.1 и выше.

Comment: C actionbarsherlock мне не понятно до конца как же заменить саму иконку и ее же сделать кликабельной, мне не нужны элементы меню справа. С ними я более менее разобрался!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ActionBar.setIcon* и *ActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled*.

Для изменения иконки можете также изменить значение атрибута *android:icon* соответствующего элемента *<activity>* в *AndroidManifest.xml*.